# How to make TDengine background execute?

Tags: tdengine

I found that I used to open two terminals, one for 'taosd' to start the server and the other for 'taos' to input sql command. However, once the taosd is shut down, client of TDengine cannot normally work:

```
Welcome to the TDengine shell from Linux, Client Version:2.1.3.0
Copyright (c) 2020 by TAOS Data, Inc. All rights reserved.

taos connect failed, reason: Unable to establish connection.
```

I am wondering is there a way to start TDengine server by starting background?

Answer (score 0):

Once installed, you could try to use systemd to start the server like "systemctl start taosd" to start server process as daemon.

Answer (score 0):

you can use do these in two ways:

1. `sudo systemctl start taosd`
2. if you are in a container or WSL. Use linux nohup command to do this.`nohup taosd 2>&1 &`